# Add Android platforms/system images via shell

Tags: android, shell, ant

I want my Centos server to build my android projects. I've configured most of the requirements so far (SDK, JDK, Ant). Right now, I'm stuck with having no system images in my SDK/platforms. How can I add some? I don't have a GUI, so I need to do it via shell or ftp.

Are the system images same for all OSes? Can I just ftp the ones I have on my desktop (Windows)?

Comment: You merely need to unpack the right ones in the right place, but I'm not absolutely sure they are portable between windows and linux.  A search will find instructions for grabbing the xml file listing them and wget'ing the individual archives.  Note you don't need system images to build, but only to emulate - do you mean to do that on the headless build machine?

Comment: Not emulating. Need to compile and sign. It is a headless server. If I don't have a system image, then how will the project compile against the target? Doesn't it need the android jar, which is in /platforms?

Comment: You only need images for emulating.  For compiling you need sdk platforms.

Comment: I guess I was confusing the terms. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ android list sdk
$ android update sdk --no-ui
```

Comment: Please include some description with your code to make the original poster understand what you mean.

Comment: @damien that these are shell commands is clear to anyone prepared to configure a headless build server, which is the target audience of the question.  Anyone else should be following the normal, official directions.